# No valid iPhone code signing keys found in keychain

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator, xamarin

So I downloaded to my Mac Pro the XCode 5 and Xamarin and created Single View Hello World application and excited to launch it through the simulator I run it and?

I got this error **No valid iPhone code signing keys found in keychain**.

Nice, I read all threads here and there, past and future but non of them helped as I just wanted to run it on the iOS simulator and not on the device.

I have realised that I cannot even switch to a different version of Simulator which are already on the laptop, the Simulator version 6 and 7 when I go to Run - Run With -> There is only Mono Soft Debugger for iPhone.

When I downloaded Tasky example project, this one is working fine and I can switch different types of Simulator.

Any advise which is not listed already on Interent or future networks?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It´s really simple, in the drop down (Solution Platforms) from the toolbar chose the right one, if you´re debugging in an iPhone/iPad chose that, if not change to simulator, the problem will go away, there´s no need for removing anything.

If you can't find the corresponding drop-down menu, check out this [tutorial](http://fetchmytip.blogspot.co.at/2014/09/xamarin-errorno-valid-ios-code-signing.html) on how to make it visible. Once you can see the Solution Platforms combobox in the toolbar, you can select iPhoneSimulation and the problem will go away.

Comment: Sometimes there isn't any iPhoneSimulator to choose in the dropdown. My projects only have "iOS Device" and "Default" as options, even though the build configuration settings are exactly the same as other projects (HTTPClient, MapDemo) that have the exact same settings, but have various iPhoneSimulator configurations selectable.

Comment: This did not work for me. I have chosen the correct device but get the error.I should mention that I am willing to test on Physical device.

Comment: I will choose it as a right answer as soon as I get the same problem and will sort it out this way :)

Answer (score 21):

After two days of no sleep I found a solution for this particular problem, not sure if it is the best one but here you are, one of this should work:

1) Go to Project -> Solution Options -> Configurations

I have removed: Release|iPhone, Debug|iPhone and this is where it started working also for any other project.

2) Maybe before the step 1) just try to change in -> Configurations -> Configurations Mappings the platform from iPhone to iPhoneSimulator.

If this is not going to work, try 1)

I hope this is going to help some of you and save tons of time!!

Cheers

Comment: "After two days of no sleep I found a solution" - I know that feeling +1

Answer (score 17):

Today I had the same issue after **Xamarin** upgrade. I tried to run my application in the simulator. The solution was however different.

> Please note that all the solutions mentioned here on this page from others might have been right in certain time or are right and works in certain circumstances.

Today's solution:

Go to **Project** -> *"Name of your project" Options* -> *Build* -> *iOS Bundle Signing* -> *Custom Entitlements* - **remove** Entitlements.plist from the textbox -> Click OK

Thanks

Comment: Thank you, solved my issue. Still, I have become very reluctant on updating Xamarin as each release brings such issues.

Comment: thanks this is exactly my issue when trying to run Xamarin samples from github

Comment: Thanks for the Xamarin solution

Answer (score 2):

I have resetted my Mac Book pro keychain and I encounter this issue.

When that happens, go in XCode and ensure that you are properly logged on into your Apple ID. If so, you should see your development group, you may have to click Join once again.

[Read the following post, it explains everything](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/).

Answer (score 1):

One more solution.
In **Release** configuration I successfully built my app, but in **Debug** - had the same issue, as in topic.

Go to your startup *Project-> Options -> Build -> iOS Bundle Signing*.
Then check your *Signing Identity* and *Provisioning Profile* for each Configuration *Debug* and *Release*.

In my case **Release** configuration was setup-ed correctly (several days ago by me) with values:
- *Signing Identity*: Developer(Automatic)
- *Provisioning Profile*: Automatic

But **Debug** configuration was silently corrupted somehow:
- *Signing Identity*: Unknown (Iphone Distribution: *name of my company*)
- *Provisioning Profile*: No matching profiles found

Thus, fix your Debug configuration to be equal with Release.

Answer (score 0):

I am on MacOSX and I have encountered this issue on Xamarin Studio when debugging using Debug|iPhoneSimulation.

The error will just keep on repeating. What has worked for me was this link [Answered by KMullins](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/4129/no-valid-iphone-code-signing-keys-found-in-keychain-error#Comment_63318)

This is due to an expired profile that was renewed.