# No valid iPhone code signing keys found in keychain in xamarin

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin

I have a Xamarin project in which I am getting `Error: No valid iPhone code signing keys found in keychain.`. As suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19039175/4959077) question, I have set Configurations Mappings from iPhone to iPhoneSimulator. And its done as evident in the Build Output.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzfWGCU3Gvf0eG1jbDFiUFVCdUE/view?usp=sharing) is the screenshot:

(Dont have enough reputation to post images)

But its still giving the error. What should be done?

Comment: Check if your iOS project (`Handshake.iOS`) targets iOS 8.3

Comment: Are your certs/provisioning profiles all valid and not expired?

Comment: @MilenPavlov the ios project targets iOS 8.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by @valdentro, the development profile was not there on my machine.

[image]

After revoking and requesting a new certificate, it was working.

Comment: Mine had expired.  Doing this and re-downloading and i was working again.

Answer (score 2):

Just edit your CS.Proj file of project: Just look for "Entitlements.plist" and remove the it. I hope it will fix this issue.

Comment: that did not fix it for me, this did http://stackoverflow.com/a/33183162/169714 perhaps it is a combination of both?