# No valid iPhone code signing keys found in keychain error Xamarin even after deleted Entitlements.plist

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm getting this error **iPhone code signing keys found in keychain error Xamarin even after deleted Entitlements.plist** when trying to build the HelloWorld_iPhone app using Xamarin Studios. I understand Its require while deploy on real device but I'm building and trying to run on a simulator and still causes this issue. Is this known issue?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yeah it seems bug in Xamarin Studio It has work around that you must have AppleID just to login on XCode. Try following:

- Create an Acount @ [Apple Dev](https://developer.apple.com/) (If you don't have)
- Open XCode and Menu
- Preferences > Accounts > Add AppleID (Just Created)

[image]
<sub>(source: [apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppStoreDistributionTutorial/Art/2_addingaccount_2x.png))</sub>

- Now go back to Xamarin Studio and try to build your application again on simulator.

Try to rebuild and issues gone!!

Comment: Even if you have already done this and it was working in the past, check this area. Your login might have expired.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, there was already apple id but I clicked on ManageCertificate 
[image]

and then I added certificate by clicking on plus sign and its done.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete `Entitlements.plist` from iOS project and try to recompile project.