# "No valid iOS code signing keys found in keychain"

Tags: ios, xamarin

I want to test an iOS application using Xamarin Test Recorder using iOS simulator. To do that I want to publish the project. When trying to publish it for archive, I got this error:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets: Error: No valid iOS code signing keys found in keychain. You need to request a codesigning certificate from https://developer.apple.com. (MobileApp1.iOS)
```

Do we need a certificate to publish the project?
    When I drag and drop the .app to simulator it doesn't get installed. When I tried to install debug version it gives below error. Failed to chmod /Users/../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8A0508B3-0‌​2E8-4601-A239-B6712F‌​67FF4D/data/Library/‌​Caches/com.apple.con‌​tainermanagerd/Bundl‌​e/Application/1B8A7B‌​17-D9D0-44A6-8584-65‌​7FF1AB5815/MobileApp‌​1.app/MobileApp1 : No such file or directory" Release app also not get installed(No error or warning). Note that this is a xamarin project.What shall I do now?

Comment: Does any answer here help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039175

Comment: Do not publish it for archive, just select the `.app` in the bin/Debug folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you do not need to sign/publish your app to use it with Test Recorder.
You can start recording tests from `.app` located on `bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/` folder.

The *“No valid iOS code signing keys found in keychain”* happens when there are no provisioning profiles on your machine. The easiest fix is to create a new app from *XCode* and deploy it on the device, XCode will automatically downloads the required profiles and certificates

Comment: You **do not** need to sign the `.app` to use it w/ Test Recorder on the iPhone Simulator...

Comment: Dang, I updated the answer, added the missing word. Thanks @SushiHangover :) I should proof read the answers before hitting the answer button

Comment: No problem, assume it was a typo... just did not want the user to think they use have sign anything to record a test script. ;-)

Comment: Thank you Prashant. But when I drag and drop the .app to simulator it dosn't get installed. When I tried to install debug version it gives below error. Failed to chmod /Users/../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8A0508B3-02E8-4601-A239-B6712F67FF4D/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.containermanagerd/Bundle/Application/1B8A7B17-D9D0-44A6-8584-657FF1AB5815/MobileApp1.app/MobileApp1 : No such file or directory"              Release app also not get installed(No error or warning). Note that this is a xamarin project.What shall I do now?

Comment: THAT WAS EASY. Just fired up XCode and made a dummy app. Fixed problem on VS2017 (15.4) with XCode 9.